# How to automatically merge cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, merge

I have an Excel table with several items 1, 2, 3..., each of which has subitems 1.1, 1.2, etc. I'm using the list of subitems as my key column and populating the main items using vlookups, but only showing each main item once.

```
/|    A    |    B     |    C     |
-+---------+----------+----------+
1| Item1   |  1.Note  |  Item1.1 |
2|         |          |  Item1.2 |
3|         |          |  Item1.3 |
4| Item2   |  2.Note  |  Item2.1 |
5|         |          |  Item2.2 |
6|         |          |  Item2.3 |
7|         |          |  Item2.4 |
8| Item3   |  3.Note  |  Item3.1 |
9|         |          |  Item3.2 |
0|         |          |  Item3.3 |
```

Column `C` is raw data; `A` and `B` are formulas.

Column `B` has notes, so the text may be long. I want to wrap the notes to take up all the rows available. I can do this manually by selecting `B1:B3` and merging them, but then it won't update if I add items to column `C`.

I don't care if the cells are merged or just wrapped and overlapping.

Can this be done in formulas or VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Extending Jon Fournier's answer, I've changed the range calculation to look for non-blank cells and added code to turn off the warning dialog that Merge throws up. I also changed the function to Public so I could run it from the Macros dialog.

```
Public Sub AutoMerge()

Dim LastRowToMergeTo As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

LastRow = Range("S" & CStr(Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    LastRowToMergeTo = i
    Do While (Len(Range("D" & CStr(LastRowToMergeTo + 1)).Value) = 0) And (LastRowToMergeTo <> LastRow)
        LastRowToMergeTo = LastRowToMergeTo + 1
    Loop

    With Range("D" & CStr(i) & ":D" & CStr(LastRowToMergeTo))
        .Merge
        .WrapText = True
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
    End With

    i = LastRowToMergeTo

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Jon's second part, which should run the macro at every recalculate, doesn't seem to work but doesn't matter to me for the small amount of updating I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using VBA, thought I don't know if you can do it without VBA.  Basically what you would do is every time your worksheet calculates you run the code to re-merge the cells.

I built a simple spreadsheet similar to yours and put the following code in the sheet's code module:

```
Private Sub AutoMerge()

Dim LastRowToMergeTo As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("C" & CStr(Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    LastRowToMergeTo = Range("B" & CStr(i)).End(xlDown).Row - 1
    LastRowToMergeTo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(LastRowToMergeTo, LastRow)

    With Range("B" & CStr(i) & ":B" & CStr(LastRowToMergeTo))
        .Merge
        .WrapText = True
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
    End With

    i = LastRowToMergeTo

Next i

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    AutoMerge
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this looks promising.  Unfortunately Range("B" & CStr(i)).End(xlDown).Row doesn't work because the cells that show empty are not, they contain formulas.  The code merges the entire column to the bottom of the last subitem.

Comment: I can iterate through the cells looking for the next non-blank cell.  The problem is that merge pops up a dialog box every time asking if I'm sure I want to overwrite all the cells being merged.  Any way to get rid of the dialog box?